# Forge Viewer Custom Shaders

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I've done some research towards Shaders and I found this:

https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/forge-viewer-custom-shaders-part-1

My question is. It seems like that won't just change the color, it changes the material, meaning that you can't undo it. In my scenario we would need to be able to undo it (resetting color and material). Could I somehow make this possible?

Answer (score 1):

To undo those changes, you have to do something to keep the relations between original materials and the id of the Forge fragment. For example, you can create an array to remember this mapping in the function `setMaterial`, like this way:

```
setMaterial( fragIds, material ) {

    const fragList = this._viewer.model.getFragmentList();

    // Array for kepping original materials of the Forge fragment.
    if( !Array.isArray( this.materialMap ) ) {
        this.materialMap = [];
    }

    this.toArray(fragIds).forEach( ( fragId ) => {
          // Keep material relations.
          const originalMat = fragList.getMaterial( fragId );
          this.materialMap[fragId] = originalMat;

          fragList.setMaterial( fragId, material );
    });

    this._viewer.impl.invalidate( true );
}
```

For restoring materials, you can follow this way:

```
restoreMaterials() {

  if( !Array.isArray( this.materialMap ) ) return;

  for( let fragId in this.materialMap ) {
      const material = this.materialMap[fragId];
      fragList.setMaterial( fragId, material );
  }

  this._viewer.impl.invalidate( true );
  // Clean mappings.
  this.materialMap.length = 0;
}
```